# Is it haram to indirectly use a hacked Facebook account without harming the person or using his account?

Tags: halal-haram, sin

So i want to start a certain agency. Wich sells advertise acocunt from facebook business manager. Company’s and ecommerce shops rent them from us. So in order to have high limit accounts this company uses hacked facebook accounts wich in them self are worthless but its only to create a business managers so i can create advertise accounts with high limits. And rent them out. The facebook account itself wont get used i dont even log in to it at all after making a business manager. this services is provided by a legal company selling on their website and is one of the largest facebook agency account provider. all kinds of businesses use their service. is it oke for me to use their business manager wich they create themself and rent them out as im not gaining anything from the hacked person account or log in to their account or give them any issue. but only the business manager account that gets created for me. that has nothing to do with the facebook account.